# Need to extract particular excel cell value in python code

Tags: python-3.x, excel

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['202009 - Shantanu.xlsm']),sheet_name='1 D',header=16,usecols=['Shift Details','Total Hours'])
df1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['202009 - Shantanu.xlsm']),sheet_name='1 D',header=3)
df = df.rename({'Shift Details': 'Activity', 'Total Hours': 'Hours'}, axis=1)
df=df.assign(ContractNo='McKay2021')
df=df.assign(PlodDate='D5') #Instead of D5 I want date value
df=df.assign(PlodShift='D6') #Instead of D6 I want shift value
```

Code Attached in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Q9naFqdfe8GrARSubsD9jCw2y3GAa5Xx?usp=sharing)

Excel File [Attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qAzsxlX3A70Or4E0-lxDLelxYaN8YkDc/view?usp=sharing)

Problem: How to get the value of a particular cell  of excel worksheet in python? Last two lines of the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **xlrd** library for that, `pip install xlrd` would help.
This link would help you in getting the exact cell value:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/